# Why take '<' as 'operator<' rather than a mark to enclose the template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

My C++ code is below:

```
//test.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <int SIZE, class T>
struct A
{
    void g(int x, const T& t)
    {
        t.f<SIZE>(x);
    }
};

struct B
{
    template <int SIZE>
    void f(int x) const
    {
        cout << SIZE << ": " << x << endl;
    }
};


int main(void)
{
    A<3, B> a;
    B b;
    a.g(9, b);
    return 0;
}
```

I got a surprising error when compiled it with g++(version is `4.8.2`):

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void A<SIZE, T>::g(int, const T&) [with int SIZE = 3; T = B]’:
test.cpp:27:13:   required from here
test.cpp:9:12: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’
         t.f<SIZE>(x);
            ^
```

Why it take `<` as `operator<` rather than a mark to enclose the template argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the code is inherently ambiguous<sup>1</sup> so the compiler has to decide either way. And it was arbitrarily decided by the C++ standards committee that *if in doubt, assume that a name is a variable, not a type*.

If you want your code to be parsed as a template, you need to say so explicitly:

```
t.template f<SIZE>(x);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> At the time where this code is parsed, the type of `t` is not yet known since it’s a template. Consider the following type:

```
struct T {
    int f;
};
```

If you now instantiate `A` with that type, you get (pseudocode since the template is instantiated):

```
void A<3, T>::g(int x, T const& t) {
    ((t.f) < 3) > x;
}
```

I’ve added parentheses for clarification: this is how the compiler sees your code, and it’s entirely valid (although nonsensical).

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at:

```
t.f < SIZE > (x);
```

Whitespace is not significant. If `t.f`is a variable this could be saying: Do `t.f < SIZE` and then do (that result) `> x`.

Further, the compiler doesn't know yet whether `t.f` is a variable or a function template. Remember that templates can be specialized, so even if it seems that `t.f` is a function template now; later on in the piece this code could be instantiated from a specialization of `B` where `t.f` is a variable.

To resolve this dilemma, names which are ambiguous are treated as variable names unless you specifically indicate that they are something else.  In this case that's done by writing `t.template f` ; a similar principle has us write `typename T::iterator` when `T` is a dependent name.

Comment: I think `t.f < SIZE` comes first.